# Асинхронные запросы к телеграмм боту

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я реализовал асинхронные запросы на каждого пользователя для телеграмм бота, чтобы приходили уведомления, использую библиотеку `aiogram`, но вот уведомления то приходят, а вот общаться с ботом я не могу, команды отправляю а он не реагирует, но за то в это же время мне уведомления присылает, можете пожалуйста помочь мне с этой проблемой. Для реализации асинхронных запросов я использую библиотеку `threading`, а для записи и получения данных с БД использую `MySQL`

Вот код:

```
import config
import logging
from sqlighter import SQLighter
from Requests_inquiry import req
import requests
import time
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from read_sql_config import read_db_config
from threading import *

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
import aiogram.utils.markdown as md

# Логи
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Инициализация бота

bot = Bot(token=config.api_token)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

# инициализируем соединение с БД
db_config = read_db_config()
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)

class Form(StatesGroup):
    add_wallet = State()
    add_name_wallet = State()  
    gender = State()


# Кнопки
inline_btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Добавить токен', callback_data='button1')
inline_kb1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(inline_btn_1)


# Функции кнопок
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button1')
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id,
                           'Введите пожалуйста свой токен от Tronscan:')
    await Form.add_wallet.set()


# Приветствие бота
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def welcome(massage: types.Message):
    await massage.answer('✌ Добро пожаловать в Tronscan-BotFather! \
        \n\n  Данный бот предназначен для удобного ползования платформы "Tronscan.org", через телеграм бота'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ,reply_markup=inline_kb1)


# Запись кошелька
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.add_wallet)
async def process_add_wallet(massage: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """
    Process user add_wallet
    """
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['add_wallet'] = massage.text
    reply, msg = req.checking_token(data['add_wallet'])
    await massage.reply(msg)
    if reply == True:
        await Form.next()


# Запись название токена
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.add_name_wallet)
async def process_add_name_wallet(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """
    Process user add_name_wallet
    """
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['add_name_wallet'] = message.text
        await message.answer(f"Регистрация успешно произведена!!! \
            \nНазвание твоего токена: {data['add_name_wallet']} \
            \nТвой токен: {md.text(data['add_wallet'])}")
        cursor.execute(
                "INSERT INTO `users` (`id_telegram`, `wallet`, `name_wallet`) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)",
                (message.from_user.id, md.text(data['add_wallet']), data['add_name_wallet']))
        conn.commit()
    await state.finish()


# Исключение ошибок и команда cancel
@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands='cancel')
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='cancel', ignore_case=True), state='*')
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """
    Allow user to cancel any action
    """
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return

    logging.info('Cancelling state %r', current_state)
    await state.finish()
    await message.reply('Cancelled.', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())

def requests_massage(user_id, id_telegram, wallet, name_wallet):
    db_config = read_db_config()
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
        cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)
        sort = '-timestamp'  # Сортировка транзакций (-timestamp нынешнее время)
        limit = 5  # Количество выводимых транзакций
        response = requests.get('https://apilist.tronscan.org/api/transaction',
            params={
                'address': wallet,
                'limit': limit,
                'sort': sort,
            })
        # Перебор и фильтрация значений для transitions
        for num in range(0, limit):
            link = 'https://tronscan.org/#/transaction/' + response.json()['data'][num]['hash']
            temporary_id = str(id_telegram) + link
            print(link)
            cursor.execute(f"""SELECT temporary_id FROM transactions WHERE temporary_id = '{temporary_id}'""")
            if cursor.fetchone() is None:
                in_address = response.json()['data'][num]['ownerAddress']
                to_address = response.json()['data'][num]['toAddress']
                result = response.json()['data'][num]['result']
                count_tokens = int(response.json()['data'][num]['amount']) / 1000000
                if count_tokens == 1.0e-06:
                    count_tokens = '{0:.6f}'.format(count_tokens)
                token = response.json()['data'][num]['tokenInfo']['tokenName'].upper()
                token_logo = response.json()['data'][num]['tokenInfo']['tokenLogo']
                time_stamp = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time.localtime(response.json()['data'][num]['timestamp'] / 1000))
                print(time_stamp)
                time_rus = time_stamp.replace('Mon', 'Пн').replace('Tue', 'Вт').replace('Wed', 'Ср').replace('Thu','Чт').replace(
                 'Fri', 'Пт') \
                 .replace('Sat', 'Сб').replace('Sun', 'Вс').replace('Jan', 'Янв').replace('Feb', 'Фев') \
                 .replace('Mar', 'Март').replace('Apr', 'Апр').replace('May', 'Май').replace('Jun', 'Июнь') \
                 .replace('Jul', 'Июль').replace('Aug', 'Авг').replace('Sep', 'Сен').replace('Oct', 'Окт') \
                 .replace('Nov', 'Ноя').replace('Dec', 'Дек')
                args = (temporary_id, user_id)
                button = '{"inline_keyboard": [[{"text": "Транзакция","url": "' + link + '"}]]}'
                print(button)
                # time.sleep(1)
                requests.get(
                    f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{config.api_token}/sendMessage?',
                    params={
                        'chat_id': id_telegram,
                        # 'parse_mode': 'markdown',
                        # 'parse_mode': 'HTML',
                        # 'reply_markup': button,
                        # 'photo': 'https://sun9-64.userapi.com/impg/ckZywaGYa5Brs8_NjgOdC5hdwwbmepl65HEGyw/xjIH0xnXsSI.jpg?size=991x1114&quality=96&sign=4b4050b6b038aaa4832216f47e3cfd47&type=album',
                        'text': (f"Твой кошелек: {name_wallet}\nРезультат: {result}\n {link}")
                    })
                cursor.execute(
                    "INSERT INTO transactions(temporary_id, user_id)"
                    "VALUES (%s, %s)", args)
                conn.commit()
                cursor.execute(
                    "DELETE FROM `transactions` WHERE id < (SELECT MAX(id) - 5 FROM (SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE user_id = %s ORDER BY id DESC) tmp) and user_id = %s", (user_id, user_id,))
                conn.commit()
            else:
                pass
    except:
        pass

# Перебор полученных данных с БД
def iter_row(cursor, size=10):
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(size)
        if not rows:
            break
        for row in rows:
            yield row 

# Запрос к БД на получение информации о пользователе
def brute_force():
    while True:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
        for row in iter_row(cursor, 10): 
            if row[4] == 0:
                pass
            else:
                starting1 = Thread(target=requests_massage, args=(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3],))
                starting1.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    starting = Thread(target=brute_force)
    starting.start()
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Что конкретно Вы подразумеваете под общением с ботом? Не вижу у Вас в коде ни одной реализации команды.

Comment: @MyZik отредактировал